# Pygame.mouse.set_cursor((8,8),(0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)) is causing errors

Tags: python, pygame

I googled how to make an invisible mouse cursor, and this is what all sources said to include.

```
pygame.mouse.set_cursor((8,8),(0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

The problem is that it's sporadially causing crashes, giving me this error:
pygame.error: CreateIconIndirect(): The parameter is incorrect.

Can someone tell me what could be causing this? Or a better way to get an invisible mouse cursor would be great too, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction

```py
pygame.mouse.set_cursor((8,8),(0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

works fine. The issue is related to your system.

However, you can use [`pygame.mouse.set_visible()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_visible) to hide the mouse cursor:

```py
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: I know this is broad, but what do you think could possibly be wrong with my system?

Comment: @bad_coder Sorry I don't know. I don't even know your system.